# RGBDSLAM Frequency

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd, bumblebee, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the Bumblebee to perform visual Slam just by remapping the RGBD SLAM package to take data from the stereo camera instead of the Kinect. The results that i got are not as good as the ones that i have with the Kinect. When i come back to a region that i already scanned, the superposition of the pointclouds is not perfect. I am acquiring data at 5Hz from the Bumblebee. Can this be a problem of Frequency ? What is the optimal frequency to work with the RGBDSLAM package ? is it 30 fps ?

My Raw poinclouds : http://youtu.be/Q2XjwYp_lv0

RGBDSLAM : http://youtu.be/xYnkozAjO9E

Do you guys have ant idea to enhance these results ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62682/rgbdslam-frequency/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen your video, maybe your Bumblebee have not been calibrated correctly, because your depth image was incorrect, please calibrate your sensor then run RGBDSLAM

---

Originally posted by [bluking](https://answers.ros.org/users/24456/bluking/) with karma: 31 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0